# How to change Drive Letter?

Tags: windows, dual-boot

I have dual boot (windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.04) I removed the system reserved partition letter from windows (desk management) and it ended for me with grub rescue terminal.

I think this means fail to find boot of both Windows and Ubuntu so how do I change back the letter? I prefer GUI more than terminal. The content of the system reserved partition didn't change so its only how will I change it back and I don't want to loose my system. I'm using Ubuntu live CD now.

I've read the old post here but it doesn't help me

Comment: There is no such thing as drive letters in Ubuntu.  It sounds like you deleted the Ubuntu partition by mistake.

Comment: Does Linux boot? If no, please run a Live-CD and give us the output of `sudo fdisk -l`.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that your dual boot was managed by the Windows boot loader.

It seems also that you have deleted the partition "system reserved" witch is needed by windows for booting (that partition does not have letter even under windows, it is a hidden partition needed by windows for it's boot process).

You need to repair windows 7. See this [link](http://itexpertvoice.com/home/rescue-windows-7-in-five-minutes-or-less/) at method 2

Then you'll need to redo your dualboot with ubuntu (see [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows))

Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu does not use drive letters, so you may not be able to change them on Ubuntu. You can use programs like Partition Magic in windows to change the drive letters.

If you have a Windows rescue disk I would consider using it.